# Event Receiver Itemadded update item

Tags: list, event-handling

I am uploading a document to a SharePoint library, (drafts lists).

When I publish the document it gets added to the startpage of the document.

When I then what do Unpublish the document the documents adds to the drafts lists again, on unpublish event I want to add custom code to clear a field in the document.

I have created a ItemAdding event receiver.

//check for manually unpublished

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
```

{
    SPWeb myWeb = properties.Web;

> how could check if the user manually do the action unpublish, if the user does that
>   then to the code in the bottom

```
string columnToUpdate = "Field_Information";
string internalName = properties.ListItem.Fields[columnToUpdate].InternalName;
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
item[internalName] = string.Empty;
item.Update();
base.ItemAdding(properties);
```

}

Comment: What SharePoint version (2010/2013?) do you use?

Comment: 2013 @Greg my field wont also update

Answer (score 0):

For SP 2013 you can check [SPItemEventProperties.IsBackgroundSave property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.isbackgroundsave.aspx).

> Gets a Boolean value that indicates whether the current update operation was triggered by a non-user gesture like a background thread or automated save.

Edit:

```
if (!properties.IsBackgroundSave)
{
//your code to handle user manual unpublish
}
```

Comment: can u perhaps give a example?